# Method "PasteSpecial" of object "TextRange2" failed when copying from Excel to PPT

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I've been searching for quite a while and can't seem to find a solution. I'm trying to copy multiple cells from Excel into a PPT textbox, keeping text only. The code I have seems to work well, but it will randomly error out with the message 'Method "PasteSpecial" of object "TextRange2" failed' When I hit debug, and play, it will continue as normal.

I've tried adding a delay wait since I know the clipboard can get flaky sometimes, but that hasn't seemed to help.

I also came across this post and have tried it but it still randomly errors out: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-vba-flaky-clipboard/3aee03af-b0be-4664-8d17-79e0507210e7

Does anyone know why this error happens randomly and it doesn't even seem to be a real error given I can just hit "play" and it will continue normally.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
Sub AddText()

Set oPPTApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
oPPTApp.Visible = True

For x = 1 to 3

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OpenEndChartingNEW").Range("A" & x & ":A" & x * 2).Copy
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.slides(6).Shapes("OpenEnd").TextFrame2.TextRange.PasteSpecial msoClipboardFormatPlainText

Next x

Set oPPTApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing your code it is not possible to help you. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to enhance your question.

Comment: Hi Ike, sorry about that - I've added a snippet of my code now. Thanks